# Chant for/on someone

Tags: grammar

If you're chanting someone's name again and again to support them, do you chant "on them" or "for them" or is "chanting" not used in that way?

The crowd started chanting his name.

The crowd were still chanting on/for him.

Comment: To chant / shout / call ***for*** X would normally be understood as meaning the crowd are impatient for X to ***appear before them*** (if X is a person, an entertainer or similar), OR that they want X to be ***implemented*** (if X is a ***policy***, say). It's not valid to use preposition ***on*** with such verbs. If X is a person who's not physically present anyway (and thus *can't* appear before the crowd if "called for") you can't necessarily expect ***for*** to be understood as meaning ***in support of***. You should express that meaning ***explicitly***, not just through a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "to sing something continuously", you can chant **for**/**to** him.

> It reminded me of when I was little, and Mom chanted **to** me in Farsi every night before bedtime.

If you mean "to utter/shout something repeatedly", you can chant **at** him.

> The football fans chanted *insults* **at** the referee.